# SequelizeDatabaseError: could not serialize access due to concurrent update

Tags: mocha.js, sequelize.js

In `Mocha` test `beforeEach` hook, I am trying to `destroy` all table records.

```
import { db } from '../src/db/models';

export const truncateTable = () => {
  const promises = Object.keys(db).map(key => {
    if (key !== 'Sequelize' && key !== 'sequelize') {
      console.log(key);
      return db[key].destroy({ where: {} });
    }
  });

  return Promise.all(promises);
};
```

Then in the test, I am doing this:

```
describe.only('application mutations', () => {

  beforeEach(() => truncateTable());

  ...
```

The error I am getting:

> SequelizeDatabaseError: could not serialize access due to concurrent
>   update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL/DR: in your tests, if you want a quick way to delete models and reset your DB, use `sync`.

```
describe.only('application mutations', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await db.sync({force: true})
  });
}
```

If you want to individually destroy your models, you must properly await for your promise to finish before initiating a new one. Currently, your promises are being initiated all at once, hence the Sequelize error.

```
export const truncateTable = async () => {
  const promises = Object.keys(db).map(key => {
    if (key !== 'Sequelize' && key !== 'sequelize') {
      await db[key].destroy({ where: {} });
    }
  });
};

// in your test file
describe.only('application mutations', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await truncateTable();
  });
})
```